# weblogic 10g module exception

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Hi i am getting the following error when i try to deploy to the server. What am i doing wrong.

```
  weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.paetec.paonline.core.config.ProfitAssistantCoreConfig.ds3NorthMailbox(ProfitAssistantCoreConfig.java:80)
        at com.paetec.paonline.core.config.ProfitAssistantCoreConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b4ed649d.CGLIB$ds3NorthMailbox$5(<generated>)
        at com.paetec.paonline.core.config.ProfitAssistantCoreConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b4ed649d$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e15cdb49.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: We're going to need more information than that to help out... have you checked what ds3NorthMailbox is doing on that line?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. had problems with the properties files. and yes, ds3NorthMailbox is being pulled from one of the properties files. had to convert dos end of line style to unix. Had other problems with my vdi instance. Not sure what got it rolling.